# My wifi has stopped working! How do I fix it?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, kernel, broadcom, modprobe

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell Inspiron 1525 and I have Broadcom BCM4311 Network Controller and I had been using the firmware-b43-installer package and everything was OK. But there was an update quite some time ago after which the wifi stopped working. 
Then I performed lspci -v | grep -i network -A 6
And it revealed:
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 17
Kernel Modules: ssb

So I tried changing the kernel module by: sudo modprobe -r ssb and sudo modprobe b43 
But nothing worked. Please help.

EDIT:

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312]
    Kernel modules: ssb`

`grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. And also `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: done..........!

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?  probably `linux-image-extra` is not installed.

Comment: Can you connect by wire?

Comment: uname -a: `Linux naught-Inspiron-1525 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Yes, I can connect it by wire but to my knowledge linux-image-extra is installed

Comment: Run `sudo apt install linux-generic` and reboot.

Comment: And what does `sudo modprobe b43` output?

Comment: It says it's already the newest version

Comment: No output is there for the modprobe commands. Neither `sudo modprobe b43` nor `sudo modprobe -r ssb` although sometimes it says that ssb is in use, other times no output.

Comment: This looks like a kernel bug. Try to install the 4.10 kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04`. No module is in use.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be making any difference. Still the same. Kernel module: ssb

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Hey! Look at this. I ran `rmmod ssb` and it says *Module ssb is in use by: b43*

Comment: Report it as a bug. There is no need to fight with `ssb`, it is not related. I thik that may be related to this commit. http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git/commit/?id=399500da18f7fe79699c0e4f603f8874cecb3898